# Can a Firebase Firestore document id have some sequentiality?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

It's [best practice to randomise document ids to avoid hotspots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) in Firebase Firestore. How random does an id need to be to be 'not sequential'?

For example, a bad pattern is Customer1, Customer2, Customer3 because it is sequential. Would it be okay to have ACustomer1, aCustomer2, KCustomer3. ie, what would it take to break the sequentiality; is adding a random letter at the start enough?

Let's take some ids in a collection:

- 123A47652hAShd
- 123A4asdqwafAa
- 123A4ad32a2da2f3

All of the records start 123A<FIRESTORE_RANDOM_ID>. Is it fine that the ids start the same, if there is a good amount of variability overall?

I want to export some Stripe records to firestore, all of which start txn_1234123... and for idempotency and consistency I want to use the same ids in firestore. Will it lead to hotspots since all the records in the collection start with the same 10 characters?

The new [Key Visualiser for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/key-visualizer) is a great way to check for hotspots and analyse Firestore usage patterns on *existing data*. But I'm trying to get a solid design up front, thanks everyone.

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901549/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, thanks that is helpful. That answer says firestore "will split the range being served by it and assign it to 2 machines." but it doesn't mention how it does the split

Comment: you can refer to this link : https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/_vJorp7yS1E Is it helpful?