# FireStore How can i get Collection in an order (Dess / Accen )

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collecntion Which Contain Multiple document and i want to fetch higest index document form it

[image: Flow of data 1]

[image: Flow 2]

[image: Flow 3]

I want to fetch Lat document of Customer_Info
but i dont know it value

and i dont know how to implement orderBy in collections => Document => document_Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Bill_ID` is same as the document ID, you can use `orderBy()` and `limit(1)` to get last document in that collection as shown below:

```
db.collection("(?)/Business/Customer_Info")
        .orderBy("Bill_ID", Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

However, you must ensure the field must be a `number` or the order will not be correct as Firestore orders them lexicographically.

---

You should avoid using sequential documents IDs and using a timestamp to order documents might be a better idea.

Also checkout:

- [Limitations of using sequential IDs in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894789/limitations-of-using-sequential-ids-in-cloud-firestore).
- [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#java_2)